# Connect to an external (Oracle) database using JDBC

Tags: database, cloud-foundry

I want to use CF as an app container but as CF doesn't provide an Oracle DB service I have to use an external Oracle DB. Can my Java app that runs on CF infrastructure connect to an external Oracle DB that is located on another server using JDBC?

In Google App Engine you can't use JDBC at all.

Comment: Yep, it definitely works. Just deployed an app that access an external Oracle db via JDBC.

Answer (score 1):

you should be able to. The only outbound port that is block from CloudFoundry.com I believe, is port 25 (for obvious reasons).